# PDO lastInsertId in CLI Mode

Tags: php, pdo, command-line-interface

I am working in CLI mode and i'm getting fatal error.

> Call to undefined method Supplier::lastID() in /var/www/vhosts/**********/httpdocs/content/mail/tr/critic_stock_mail.php on line 11

Normaly everything works fine in normal mode. Every one says beware using lastInsertId try catch block. But it is not true. In normal mode everything works correctly.

But i remove lastInsertId part in try catch block. In CLI mode it is not working also. what should i do ?

```
 try{
        $supplierObj->begin();

            //Mail Gönderim Tarihini Güncelliyoruz
            $sql = "UPDATE ".PREFIX."product SET supplier_mail_date = NOW() WHERE supplier = :supplier";
            $supplierObj->query($sql);
                $supplierObj->bind(':supplier', $supplier_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $supplierObj->execute();

           //Gönderilen Mailleri Tabloya Yazıyoruz...
           $sql = "INSERT INTO ".PREFIX."supplier_order (supplier_id, create_date) VALUES (:supplier_id, NOW())";
           $supplierObj->query($sql);
           $supplierObj->bind(':supplier_id', $supplier_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
           $supplierObj->execute();

           $order_id = $supplierObj->lastID();

            //Gönderilen Mailin Detaylarını tabloya yazıyoruz...
            foreach($supplier as $product){
                $sql = "INSERT INTO ".PREFIX."supplier_products (order_id, product_id, quantity, stock_up) "
                     . "VALUES (:oid, :product_id, :quantity, :stock_up)";
                $supplierObj->query($sql);
                    $supplierObj->bind(':oid', $order_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $supplierObj->bind(':product_id', $product['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $supplierObj->bind(':quantity', $product['stock_quantity'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $supplierObj->bind(':stock_up', $product['stock_up'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $supplierObj->execute();
            }
        $supplierObj->end();
    } catch (PDOException $e){
        $supplierObj->cancel();        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing the line

```
$order_id = $supplierObj->lastID();
```

to

```
$order_id = $supplierObj->lastInsertId ();
```

Comment: this is my function :) lastID calls lastInsertId